# How to read 1 million records of rows in excel using java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, streaming, spring-batch

Can anyone please help in providing a code snippet to read 1 million records from excel using java

We have XSSF apache poi,but it is not able to read 500 k records as it is trying to read entire file at once,

"GC over limit exceeded" error is being thrown

I searched over the internet but I am getting examples only to write data of 1 million records into excel using java

Comment: You cannot read 1 million record excel file evne with Excel ;)

Comment: @Veselin Davidov: Why not? [Modern Excel Worksheets](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) have 1,048,576 rows.

Comment: Read about [XSSF and SAX (Event API)](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#XSSF+and+SAX+%28Event+API%29).

Comment: Over a million rows only applies to Excel 2007 and onwards. It depends which version of Excel OP is using. However, If you have that much data, why not save it in a database which is designed to handle data of that size instead of Excel where you will be reaching the upper limits of the app and things can go horribly wrong

Comment: Why not split your job to read few thousand record each?

Comment: If the Excel files aren't simple (just one worksheet) you might want to consider just exporting the Excel files to CSV (easily done from Excel) and processing the CSV with Camel. CSV is just a text format and Camel has multiple components to process it (Bindy, or CSV http://camel.apache.org/csv.html).

Comment: can anybody give a sample snippet please

Comment: why you need load million record? if you decide to process on that, you can load data with paging.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can read 1 million records from excel using java , but you need a very big computer memory. if you run your application via eclipse , a very big memory is required. In fact , I read 181234 records via eclipse by java , it needs More than 11G memory, so , if you want to read 1 million records, think about the memory you need ......

below is the test code.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    File file = new File("C:\\opt\\upload\\1.xlsx");
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook = getXSSFWorkbook(in);
    XSSFSheet xssfSheet = xssfWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
    XSSFRow row = xssfSheet.getRow(0);
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    NetworkParas bean = new NetworkParas();
    bean.setCellId(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(0) == null ? null : row.getCell(0).toString()).intValue());
    bean.setLac(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(1) == null ? null : row.getCell(1).toString()).intValue());
    bean.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(2) == null ? null : row.getCell(2).toString()));
    bean.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(3) == null ? null : row.getCell(3).toString()));
    bean.setAntAzimuth(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(4) == null ? null : row.getCell(4).toString()).intValue());

    bean.setRat(row.getCell(5) == null ? null : row.getCell(5).toString());
    bean.setCity(row.getCell(6) == null ? null : row.getCell(6).toString());
    bean.setCell(row.getCell(7) == null ? null : row.getCell(7).toString());
    bean.setCellName(row.getCell(8) == null ? null : row.getCell(8).toString());
    bean.setLocation(row.getCell(9) == null ? null : row.getCell(9).toString());

    bean.setCellType(row.getCell(10) == null ? null : row.getCell(10).toString());
    bean.setSiteId(row.getCell(11) == null ? null : row.getCell(11).toString());
    bean.setSiteType(row.getCell(12) == null ? null : row.getCell(12).toString());
    bean.setConf(row.getCell(13) == null ? null : row.getCell(13).toString());
    bean.setAntHeight(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(14) == null ? null : row.getCell(14).toString()));

    bean.setMtilt(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(15) == null ? null : row.getCell(15).toString()));
    bean.setEtilt(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(16) == null ? null : row.getCell(16).toString()));
    bean.setNe(row.getCell(17) == null ? null : row.getCell(17).toString());
    bean.setArfcnDl(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(18) == null ? null : row.getCell(18).toString()).intValue());
    bean.setScramblingCode(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(19) == null ? null : row.getCell(19).toString()).intValue());

    bean.setCpichPower(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(20) == null ? null : row.getCell(20).toString()));
    bean.setEnbId(Double.valueOf(row.getCell(22) == null ? null : row.getCell(22).toString()).intValue());


    bean.setEci(Integer.valueOf(row.getCell(23) == null ? null : row.getCell(23).getCTCell().getV()));
    bean.setLaccellId(row.getCell(26) == null ? null : row.getCell(26).getCTCell().getV());

    System.out.println(bean);

    time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
    System.out.println("Elapsed Time :" + time);

}

public static XSSFWorkbook getXSSFWorkbook(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    XSSFWorkbook xssfWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(in);
    System.out.println("\n*** Elapsed Time: " + ((System.currentTimeMillis()-time)/1000) + "s ");
    return xssfWorkbook;
}
```